# Sforzando can playback samples, but LMMS cannot

Tags: daw

I downloaded the Standard Guitar vst by Unreal Instruments.
I import the "Guitar Chord Central.sfz" program into Sforzando.
On the sforzando it can playback the sample, but when i click the piano key on the piano roll in LMMS, nothing plays. Why is this?
Also, when I pressed, say for example, a C key, it plays F# sample... a G key, it plays B sample. Basically all of it become jumbled up.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: This sounds like something you should be asking the developers of LMMS.

Comment: This seems like a troubleshooting question best asked of LMMS Support.